# Which data structure would allow easily adding and removing items and be easy to fully destroy?

Tags: c++, data-structures, garbage-collection

I'm looking to create my own garbage collector made for a specific purpose:

- I want to be able to quickly allocate and add and remove and free many items of the same type/size
- I would like to be able to quickly wipe away all items.

Double linked list might do it since I always have a direct ref to the item. Would be nice to be able to wipe it out quickly without iterating through all items though. Maybe I just allocate in chunks since all items the same size though it makes normal add/remove slower but open to ideas.

Ideally I can do true garbage collection if someone forgot to delete an object.

Comment: That's pretty simple question with pretty complex answers. IMHO, I'd not start any work before reading [The Garbage Collection Handbook](https://gchandbook.org/). What are you into is often called "arenas" or "regions" - [start research there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Region-based_memory_management).